# Ordenar títulos de forma descendente en las filas de una matriz

Tags: c++, dev-c++, codeblocks

hola buenas pasa que estoy haciendo un programa en c++ y tengo que imprimir los goles de cada respectivo equipo, pero en cada fila tengo que concatenar cada equipo, pero nose como hacerlo al menos lo estoy intentando así, ya que se me juntan todos pero los equipos debo ponerlos en cada fila, entonces en la fila 0 de la matriz es honduras, en la fila 1 el salvador, en la fila 2 el siguiente y asi.

```
int aux;
cout<<"========================================================================\n";
cout<<"                          TABLA ESTADISTICA                             \n";
cout<<"========================================================================\n";
cout<<"SELECCIONES                    PJ   PG   PE   PP   GF   GC   DIF   PTS  \n";
//Imprimir equipos.
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{

  cout<<nombre1<<"";
  cout<<nombre2<<"";
  cout<<nombre3<<"";
  cout<<nombre4<<"";
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
    cout<<matriz[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<" \n";
}
cout<<"\n";
system("pause");
system("cls");
imprimirMenu();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debería mostrarse técnicamente Asi

Comment: Probablemente te interese poner los nombres de los equipos en un arreglo. Así seleccionas el nombre del equipo que quieres imprimir en cada línea.

Comment: el problema es que no se como hacer para que no se me dupliquen

Comment: pásanos tu código completo por favor. Edita tu pregunta y añádenos ese detalle.

Comment: es de 800 lineas , solo necesito que me digan como puedo ordenar cada nombre en una fila de la matriz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los nombres de los equipos se "duplican" porque imprimes `nombre1`, `nombre2`, `nombre3` y `nombre4` en cada iteración.

Tienes que imprimir solo uno.

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    if (i == 0) cout << nombre1;
    else if (i == 1) cout nombre2;
    else if (i == 2) cout << nombre3;
    else cout << nombre4;

    cout << " ";
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        cout << matriz[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Puedes ver que es difícil de trabajar y empeoraría si tuvieras más equipos. Una mejor manera de hacerlo es mediante un arreglo, por ejemplo:

```
char nombres[][10] = { "Honduras", "Salvador", "Francia", "Alemania" };
```

O aprovechando la clase [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
string nombres[] = { "Honduras", "Salvador", "Francia", "Alemania" };
```

Incluso si deseas agregar más elementos, puedes usar una colección como [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
vector<string> nombres[] = { "Honduras", "Salvador", "Francia", "Alemania" };
```

E imprimir solo el nombre correspondiente con `nombres[i]`:

```
//Imprimir equipos.
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    cout << nombres[i] << " ";
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        cout << matriz[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
cout << "\n";
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo

Comment: no hay una forma donde no emplee el uso de arreglos ?, ¿dónde pueda yo escribir los nombres sin que se dupliquen? es que no siempre me gustaría usar arreglos ya que en mi proyecto no siempre me los solicitas para decorar las matrices

Comment: muchísimas gracias ahora si me quedo claro, te lo agradezco que tengas buen día